# Filter recent files in Logic Apps' SFTP when files are added/modified trigger

Tags: azure, sftp, azure-logic-apps, last-modified

I have this Logic App that connects to an SFTP server and it's triggered by the "files are added or modified" trigger. It's set to run every 10 minutes, looking for new/modified files and copying them to an Azure storage account.

The problem is that this SFTP server path is set to overwrite a set of files every X minutes (I have no control over this) and so, pretty often the Logic App overlaps with the update process of these files and downloads files that are still being written. The result is corrupted files.

Is there a way to add a filter to the `When files are added or modified (properties only)` so that it only takes into consideration files with a modified date of, at least, 1 minute old?

That way, files that are currently being written won't be added to the list of files to download. The next run of the Logic App would then fetch this ignored files and so on.

**UPDATE**

I've found a Trigger Conditions in the trigger's setting but I can't find any documentation about it.
[image]

Comment: If you want to know how to use trigger condition expression, you could refer to this [trigger condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-workflow-actions-triggers#trigger-conditions), you could filter the property in the triggerbody to decide the logic app run or not.

Comment: @GeorgeChen Yeah, but that doesn't show all the possible expressions that can be used there. How would you filter by LastModified date there?

Comment: I post my answer, you could check it.

Comment: Any process on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

According to test the trigger "When files are added or modified", it seems we can not add a filter in the trigger to filter the records which are modified at least 1 minute ago. We can just get the `List of Files LastModified` datetime and loop them, use "[If](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-control-flow-conditional-statement#add-condition)" condition to judge if we should download it.

[image]

**Update:**

[image]

The expression in the screenshot is:

```
sub(ticks(utcNow()), ticks(triggerBody()?['LastModified']))
```

**Update workaround**

Is it possible to add a "Delay" action when the last modified time less than 1 minute ? For example, if the last modified time less than 60 seconds, use "Delay" to wait 5 minutes until the overwrite operation complete, then do the download.
[image]

Comment: Yes, but if I add an IF condition after the trigger, the files that don't pass the filter won't be processed at all. For the trigger all the files were taken into consideration, but then the if will discard the ones that don't have a modified timestamp of at least 1 minute old.
There is a "Trigger Conditions" in the settings of the trigger, but I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Oh you meant not using the "When files are added or modified" trigger at all and use this one instead. Ok, by using this one how would you avoid re-downloading the same files over and over again?
I've found a "Trigger Conditions" in the settings, but I can't find any documentation about it. Do you know anything about them?

Comment: Hi @emzero Sorry for the delay reply. I don't know much about the "Trigger Conditions" you mentioned, but it seems be used to judge if the trigger is fired but not a filter(from its description "Specify one or more expressions which must be true for the trigger to fire). I update my answer above. In my logic app, it will just transfer the last modified date of files which was modified or added from the trigger, so I'm not so clear about you concern of re-downloading problem.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that Condition after the trigger could end up excluding files. When the Logic App runs, it will trigger for all the newly added/modified files (based on the last execution timestamp right?), but then the next step (Condition) will filter out the ones that are not at least 1 minute old. But, as far as the Trigger concerns, those files were "processed". So the next execution will not include the filtered ones, because they are not new/modified as per the trigger. Do you get what I'm saying? Is my thinking correct?

Comment: @emzero So you want the files which last modified less than 1 minute would also be download in next trigger right ? I think it would be difficult for us to implement in logic app, I provide a workaround in the "Update workaround" in my answer. I'm not sure if it can meet your requirement, please take a look.

Comment: I'm going to try adding a Delay. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I check the sample `@equals(triggers().code, 'InternalServerError')`, actually it uses the  condition functions in [Logical comparison functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#logical-comparison-functions), so the key word is make sure the property you want to filter is in the `trigger` or `triggerBody` or you will get the below error.

[image]

So I change the expression to like `@greater(triggerBody().LastModified,'2020-04-20T11:23:00Z')`, this could filter the file modified less than `2020-04-20T11:23:00Z` not trigger the flow.

Also you could use other function like `less` ,`greaterOrEquals` etc in the [Logical comparison functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#logical-comparison-functions).